# Developing Multiple Charts through program

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I am developing an iPhone app. Where-in, I have to support multiple 3D charts (such as Bar chart, Pie chart and Line chart) through the program for showing data. I've heard by using GLKit framework I can achieve this. But I understand it will take lot of time for learning and testing the API's,... on this.

As I don't have that much time, I want to use available third-party framework/lib/SDK for drawing multiple charts. But, I want to have iOS frameworks/lib's/SDK's which I could use  to draw Bar chart, Pie Chart and Line chart *all through my program*.

Could someone help me with some ideas, suggestions, samples?

Comment: you can take some ideas from

1) http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles. Oh gods you've done it on every.. single.. one....

Answer (score 2):

I think Coreplot is the most used charting library http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ 
An other option is to use one of the many available javascript graphing libraries and use that in a UIWebView

Comment: Hi, THanks for the reply, I want the charts in 3D

Comment: I found this 3D component: http://windal.net/blog/?p=153

Answer (score 1):

For 3D plots, take a look at the [`FRD3DBarChart`](https://github.com/sebastienwindal/FRD3DBarChart) framework.